# How to exclude audio from capture on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'm trying to find a method to play audio from specific window without it getting captured by other software like OBS (similar to how SetWindowDisplayAffinity works).

I know that WASAPI provides exclusive mode for specific audio stream, but according to docs it also blocks other audio streams from accessing same endpoint which is something that I don't want.

Comment: But you can just loop physical audio-out into audio-in (with a cable) and capture it anyway.  So what's the point?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm developing a game engine. It's not meant to be a bulletproof solution or a downright DRM, but just a trick to mess with people

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [PUMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/protected-user-mode-audio--puma-), Protected User-Mode Audio. It's part of PMP, Protected Media Path. You'll need to specify an `IMFOutputPolicy`.

This *is* DRM, but that only makes sense. Windows isn't going to have a nice interface for your rather unique idea. The two normal choices are to have unprotected audio, or to make a serious attempt.